# Can't find _T or fRprintf in xutility for vs2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, graphics, raytracing

I'm trying to get [this project](http://www.codermind.com/articles/Raytracer-in-C++-Part-I-First-rays.html) to work in VS2008 Windows 7 on a 64-bits machine.
Their source code is at the bottom.

I keep getting two types of errors:

- `error C3861: 'fRprintf': identifier not found c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xutility 3605`
- `error C3861: '_T': identifier not found c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\xutility 3605`

I have been looking online for a resolution but with no luck. I'm still new to C++ so there could be something I'm missing.

One of the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707310/xutility-file) is the closest thing I have found for an answer.

The error seems to be from the `SimpleString.h` but I'm not sure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Turns out some how this line  fprintf(0, _T("unchecked_copy \n"));
 happened.<br/>
<br/>
Original<br/>
template<class _InIt,<br/>
   class _OutIt> inline<br/>
   _OutIt __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL unchecked_copy(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _OutIt _Dest)<br/>
   {   // copy [_First, _Last) to [_Dest, ...)<br/>
       return (_STD _Copy_opt(_CHECKED_BASE(_First), <br/>_CHECKED_BASE(_Last), _Dest,<br/>
           _STD _Iter_random(_First, _Dest), _STD _Ptr_cat(_First, <br/>_Dest), _STD _Range_checked_iterator_tag()));<br/>
   }<br/>

Comment: Mine  
template<class _InIt,  
   class _OutIt> inline   
   _OutIt __CLRCALL_OR_CDECL unchecked_copy(_InIt _First, _InIt _Last, _OutIt _Dest)  
   {    
       fprintf(0, _T("unchecked_copy \n"));  
       // copy [_First, _Last) to [_Dest, ...)  
       return (_STD _Copy_opt(_CHECKED_BASE(_First),   _CHECKED_BASE(_Last), _Dest,  
           _STD _Iter_random(_First, _Dest), _STD _Ptr_cat(_First,   _Dest), _STD _Range_checked_iterator_tag()));  
   }  
  
  
Not sure how this ever got changed...